# How can I loop through an array of object and get one property element out of the two objects listed inside the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, mapping

I have my array of object bellow.

```
const Articles = [
    {
        id: 1,
        article1: 1,
        title1:'Trust',
        name1:'Pericles',
        date1:'Dec 2, 2022',
        text1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit consectetur. minima in quae dolores quis fugit officia, quia at quam ipsum iste suscipit, eum, veniam eaque voluptas?',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        article2: 2,
        title2:'Love',
        name2:'Billey',
        date2:'Dec 2, 2022',
        text2: 'minima in quae dolores quis fugit officia, quia at quam ipsum iste suscipit, eum, veniam eaque voluptas?',
    }

]
```

I have a function and I am trying to select Articles.title1 through mapping

```
function  arc(){
   Articles.map((element, index)=>{    
   console.log(element.title1) 
})
```

I get `"Trust"` for the `title1` and that's all I needed but, I'm getting `undefined` for the other.
Is there a way I can have just `title1`? Thank you.

I have also tried for loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Articles.length; i++){
    console.log(Articles[i].title1)
}
```

and get the same result.

Comment: Why are your properties not consistent across objects? `title1` in one object but `title2` in the other object — no surprise that `title1` in the second object doesn’t exist. Everything should just be `title`. The same goes for `article`, `name`, `date`, and `text`.

Comment: If you can’t change the data yourself, use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods): `const [ , value ] = Object.entries(Articles[i]).find(([ key ]) => key.startsWith("title")); console.log(value);` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `title` as the key instead of `title1` and `title2`.

And for other keys, you should do the same:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  article: 1,
  title:'Trust',
  name:'Pericles',
  date:'Dec 2, 2022',
  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit consectetur. minima in quae dolores quis fugit officia, quia at quam ipsum iste suscipit, eum, veniam eaque voluptas?',
}
```